# Improve performance of RabbitMQ publish (RabbitMQ C# client)

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, publish, amqp

I'm using the following code to publish messages to a RabbitMQ queue:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory {
    HostName = hostName,
    Port = port,
    UserName = userName,
    Password = password,
    VirtualHost = "/",
    Protocol = Protocols.DefaultProtocol
};
connection = factory.CreateConnection();
channel = connection.CreateModel();
channel.QueueDeclare(queue, true, false, false, null);
foreach (string message in messages) {
    byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    channel.BasicPublish("", queue, null, body);
}
```

While publishing the messages to a local RabbitMQ server I get a message rate of up to 10,000 messages per second. The cpu load of the system (2x3.16 GHz) is at almost 100%. Is there a way to increase this message rate? My first idea was to use a bulk publish operation, but there doesn't seem to be anything like that in RabbitMQ. My second idea was using a Parallel.ForEach instead of the foreach, but that didn't change the message rate.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to send so many messages a second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining a queue as "Durable" has the added benefit of surviving a rabbit or server restart.  The downside is that to accomplish this it writes the data to disk, which is costly.

If your greatest concern is throughput and it's not a problem that you'd drop a few messages in the event of a failure than setting "Durable=false" would increase your throughput.

**Note**: Even with durable=false if the queue length becomes long enough it will dump them to disk (after all, there is only so much memory on the machine).